# Webhook: save_post action fires wp_remote_post twice

Tags: actions, wp-remote-post, headless

I am trying to implement a webhook in a plugin which should fire everytime a user saves a post. It works fine, but I recive two requests on frontend api. The first request has got a wrong slug. I wonder why this is happening or what I am doing wrong here. The second call works perfect.

```
 defined('ABSPATH') or die('Unauthorized access');

 add_action('save_post', 'update_front_end', 10, 2);
 function update_front_end($post_id, $post){

   $exovias_webhooks_options = get_option( 'exovias_webhooks_option_name' ); // Array of All Options
   $secret_0 = $exovias_webhooks_options['secret_0']; // Secret
   $frontendurl_1 = $exovias_webhooks_options['frontendurl_1']; // FrontendUrl

 
  $slug = basename(get_permalink($post_id));
  $url = $frontendurl_1 . '/api/revalidate?secret=' . $secret_0 .'&slug=' . $slug;

   wp_remote_post($url);

}
```

Comment: You should probably use the `wp_after_insert_post` hook instead - just replace the `save_post` with `wp_after_insert_post`. I don't guarantee the hook doesn't run *twice or more*, but with that hook, you should be able to get the correct slug, regardless the post was edited via the block/Gutenberg editor or the classic editor. And why didn't you use the actual post slug, i.e. `$post->post_name`, and instead, parse it from the post's permalink URL?

Comment: @SallyCJ Thanks a million for trying to help me out. I tried your beautiful solution. Looks and sounds cleaner. But unfortunately the hook is still running twice. And the first run provides a slug of "46-revision-v1" while the scnd provides the correct slug.

Comment: I posted an answer, which might help?

Comment: @SallyCJ This helped a lot. Wonderful. Thanks a million. Now just one request is left. Deep bow concerning your depth of wp knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wonder why this is happening or what I am doing wrong here

WordPress has a revisions system which stores a record of *each saved draft or published update*, and a post can have one of a number of [statuses](https://wordpress.org/support/article/post-status/) like `auto-draft` when a new post is created and saved automatically in the background, `draft` (e.g. when the post is autosaved) or `publish` (e.g. when the publish button is clicked). So the `save_post` hook (and other hooks like [`wp_after_insert_post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_after_insert_post/)) can run multiple times while editing a post, and thus you should check whether WordPress is doing an autosave and whether the post being saved is a [revision](https://wordpress.org/support/article/revisions/), before running your remote HTTP request.

Here's an example which also checks whether WordPress is doing [cron](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/) (`/wp-cron.php`) or [AJAX](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/javascript/ajax/) (`wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`), and whether the post status is `publish` or `private`:

```php
function update_front_end( $post_id, $post ) {
    $doing_autosave = ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE );

    if ( $doing_autosave || wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ||
        wp_doing_cron() || wp_doing_ajax()
    ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( in_array( $post->post_status, array( 'publish', 'private' ) ) ) {
        // your code here; define the $url, etc.

        // now run your remote HTTP request
        wp_remote_post( $url );
    }
}
```